# How to extract uppercased attributes with Cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, attributes, cheerio

I have a log entry as below:

```html
<Event Timestamp="2017-06-14T10:17:09.313991+10:00" Level="INFO" Identity=""><Message>Accessed Page: </Message></Event>
```

I'd like to extract the attribute like Timestamp, Level with Cheerio. What I did is like this:

```js
const $ = cheerio.load(line)
console.log($("Event").attr('Timestamp'))
```

However, I just get undefined in the console. Could you please advise where is the problem?

Comment: What do you get if you log `$("Event")`?

Comment: Hi tavnab, thanks for your asking. It displays the JSON object information of the Event. From the JSON object I found the attribute name is low-cased. So I change the code to console.log($("Event").attr('timestamp')). It works. thanks for your asking again.

Comment: Cool, good to know :) feel free to answer your own question & accept it, if that was the issue

Answer (score 3):

`.attr()` is the correct Cheerio method call, but this XML is being parsed in the default HTML mode. In HTML mode, Cheerio lowercases attributes, which you can see with `console.log($.html());` after loading it.

Adding `{xml: true}` preserves casing, assuming you're dealing with XML:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const xml = `
<Event Timestamp="2017-06-14T10:17:09.313991+10:00" Level="INFO" Identity=""><Message>Accessed Page: </Message></Event>
`;

const $ = cheerio.load(xml, {xml: true});
console.log($("Event").attr("Timestamp")); // => 2017-06-14T10:17:09.313991+10:00
```

If this is actually HTML, then you can extract the field using a lowercased attribute name:

```js
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
console.log($("Event").attr("timestamp")); // => 2017-06-14T10:17:09.313991+10:00
```